# Mysql error 150 with creating a table that has a foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql

I am getting error 150 on the following create statement:

```
CREATE TABLE `lazarus`.`warehouses_devices` (
  `parent_unit_id` INT UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `child_unit_id` INT UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `message_type` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  `date` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `value` LONGTEXT NOT NULL,
  INDEX `parent_unit_id` (`parent_unit_id` ASC),
  INDEX `child_unit_id` (`child_unit_id` ASC),
  INDEX `message_type` (`message_type` ASC),
  INDEX `date` (`date` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_parent_unit_id_unit_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`parent_unit_id`)
    REFERENCES `lazarus`.`logs` (`unit_id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_general_ci
```

And I am not sure why, I look up error 150 and it states that its foreign key issues and I am really confused as the reason isn't very clear.

The exact error is `ERROR 1005: Can't create table 'lazarus.warehouses_devices' (errno: 150)`

Comment: Run `show warnings;` after executing the failing `create table` to display the real problem.

Comment: @Xint0 Its the same error

Comment: Then try `show innodb status;` to see extended error information.

Comment: it doesn't like that, when I do ` SHOW INNODB STATUS` it complains on the `INNODB` part. Stating its a syntax error

Comment: Sorry about that, I was missing the `engine` part it should be `show engine innodb status`.  If you are executing this using `mysql` command line utility, then use `\G` to display results vertically: `show engine innodb status\G`.

Comment: This spits out a lot of info, what are you looking for specifically out of curiosity?

Comment: The section "LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR" should contain some more clear explanation of the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html):

> InnoDB does not currently support foreign keys for tables with
>   user-defined partitioning. This means that no user-partitioned InnoDB
>   table may contain foreign key references or columns referenced by
>   foreign keys.

`logs` is partitioned, while `warehouses_devices` is not.

Answer (score 1):

Considering that you already have a table created called `logs` 
which has `unit_id` set as primary key. Most probably the error is causing due to datatype mismatch between referred column and referring column.

Then you probably need to check that the column `parent_unit_id` in `warehouses_devices` has the same data type as in `logs` (`unit_id`).

Make sure both in `lazarus`.`warehouses_devices` the `parent_unit_id INT UNSIGNED`

In `logs` table as well the `unit_id` must be `INT UNSIGNED`

Also, in your `CREATE TABLE lazarus.warehouses_devices (` you are creating a constraint named 
`fk_parent_unit_id_unit_id`. make sure you don't have another constraint with the same name already created in some other table.

Comment: `unit_id` and `parent_unit_id` are the same type, `unit_id` in the logs table is not a primary key. There is no other FK with this name. I understand that you can create fk's on non primary key table rows. that is unit_id doesn't have to be a pk

Comment: @user3379926, are you sure about you can create fk's on non primary key column? I don't think so. Try creating a sample table with one col and then try adding FK on that col. MySQL will throw an error. It's as well violates the concept of referential integrity. You can't refer a non-key column. Finally, I think that's the error. make `unit_id` in `logs` as primary key and things will work fine.

Comment: @user3379926, may or may not be. Try creating foriegn key on a key column. Your issue is that, you are creating FK on a non-key column. Hope you understood now.

Comment: It does allow you to do it according to the docs, see my answer, but the issue si that I have a table that's partitioned.

Comment: @user3379926, Man!!! no where in your post this point is mentioned (logs is partitioned). It's your fault ... else you would have got a straight forward answer. Again, you are reading the docs wrongly. Per docs, on partitioned table FK not supported on InnoDB but that doesn't defy the point in my answer; cause it's against generic DBMS concept.

Comment: @user3379926, Just chill. I am not yelling at you at all. Just trying to give you a clarification. Moreover, I learned something new today from your answer.